# WIndows MAPI unicode issue

Tags: windows, winapi, unicode, mapi

It seems to me that MAPI (Windows Mail API) has issues with UTF8 (or maybe I did something wrong).

Code sample:

```
HMODULE m_hLib = LoadLibraryA("MAPI32.DLL");
if (m_hLib == NULL)
    return SEND_MAIL_CANCELED;
LPMAPISENDMAIL SendMail;
SendMail = (LPMAPISENDMAIL) GetProcAddress(m_hLib, "MAPISendMail");
if (!SendMail)
    return;

MapiFileDesc fileDesc;
ZeroMemory(&fileDesc, sizeof(fileDesc));
fileDesc.nPosition = (ULONG) -1;
fileDesc.lpszPathName = (LPSTR) filePath.toUtf8();
fileDesc.lpszFileName = (LPSTR) fileName.toUtf8();

MapiRecipDesc recipientData;
ZeroMemory(&recipientData, sizeof(recipientData));
recipientData.lpszName = (LPSTR) recipient.toUtf8();
recipientData.ulRecipClass = MAPI_TO;

MapiMessage message;
ZeroMemory(&message, sizeof(message));
message.ulReserved = CP_UTF8;
message.lpszSubject = (LPSTR) title.toUtf8();
message.nFileCount = 1;
message.lpFiles = &fileDesc;
message.nRecipCount = 1;
message.lpRecips = &recipientData;

int nError = SendMail(0, NULL, &message, MAPI_LOGON_UI | MAPI_DIALOG, 0);
```

`title`, `filePath`, `fileName` and `recipient` are all `std::string`s. As far as I know, UTF8 is compatible with ASCII (also NULL terminated), so its string can hold such values without any problems.

I'm converting to UTF8 from wstring in this way:

```
int requiredSize = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, data.c_str(), -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
if(requiredSize > 0)
{
    std::vector<char> buffer(requiredSize);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, data.c_str(), -1, &buffer[0], requiredSize, 0, 0);
    this->container.append(buffer.begin(), buffer.end() - 1);
}
```

`container` is a `std::string` object.

Comment: What is the actual question here? What are you expecting to happen, and what are you getting instead?

Answer (score 8):

`MAPISendMail()` does not support UTF-8, only Ansi.  If you need to send Unicode data, you have to use [`MAPISendMailHelper()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802867.aspx) on Windows 7 and earlier, or [`MAPISendMailW()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707275.aspx) on Windows 8 and later.  This is clearly stated in the [`MAPISendMail()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd296721.aspx).

On a side note, `WideCharToMultiByte()` includes the null terminator when you set the `cchWideChar` parameter to -1.  As such, you are encoding and including that null terminator in your `container` data.  You should instead set `cchWideChar` to the actual length of the string to avoid the null terminator completely:

```
int requiredSize = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, data.c_str(), data.length(), 0, 0, 0, 0); 
if (requiredSize > 0) 
{ 
    std::vector<char> buffer(requiredSize); 
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, data.c_str(), data.length(), &buffer[0], requiredSize, 0, 0); 
    container.append(buffer.begin(), buffer.end()); 
}
```

On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd296721.aspx it states "On Windows 7 and earlier: Use MAPISendMailHelper to send a message" but at the bottom of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802867.aspx it states "Minimum supported" is Windows 8. Seems like contradictory information and therefore it's unclear whether MAPISendMailHelper is really for Windows 7 and earlier.

Comment: MAPISendMailHelper does not exist on Windows 7 Service Pack 1. I used depends.exe in order to retrieve the exported functions of mapi32.dll. MAPISendMailHelper is not exported by mapi32.dll.

Comment: MAPISendMailHelper is not exported from any dll; it is supplied as code in the latest Windows SDK. It's in the file "MapiUnicodeHelp.h".

Comment: Under Win7 and earlier, MAPISendMailHelper() simply converts the Unicode structs to ANSI structs and calls MapiSendMail() instead of MapiSendMailW(). In other words, it does not support Unicode MAPI unless the underlying MAPI provider does (I.e., Win8 MAPI). Its only purpose is to simplify client code--you don't have to build different structs and call different functions depending on the Windows version.

Comment: Incidentally, all the code is there to look at in MapiUnicodeHelp.h. MAPISendMailHelper() isn't a DLL export, it's code that gets #included into your project.

Comment: Actually `MAPISendMail()` does utilize UTF8 on Windows 7, but you have to add a registry key `DWORD` `SupportUTF8` (value `1` usually) under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\YourAppName`. If added, it will set `ULONG ulReserved` of the `MAPISendMail()` to `CP_UTF8` and you can use `MultiByteToWideChar` to convert into widechars.